# Grep multiple lines with different patterns

Tags: text-processing, grep, aix

I have this test.debug file in AIX unix with the following fields:

```
in[  2: ]<0000********0000>  
in[  3: ]<0>  
in[  4: ]<000000020000>  
in[  7: ]<1113>  
in[  7: ]<80402>  
in[ 11: ]<5530>  
in[ 12: ]<181113>  
in[ 12: ]<90254>  
in[ 17: ]<1113>  
in[ 19: ]<960>  
in[ 22: ]<510101510000>  
in[ 24: ]<400>  
in[ 25: ]<4021>  
in[ 26: ]<7011>  
in[ 28: ]<181115>  
in[ 30: ]<000000020000>  
in[ 32: ]<000090>  
in[ 33: ]<589638>  
in[ 37: ]<000000000132>  
in[ 41: ]<75000001>  
in[ 42: ]<01111111111    >  
in[ 49: ]<960>
in[ 56: ]<110000553018111309025406000004>  
in[128: ]<98D6F81BFFFFFFFF>

out[000: ]<ISO9090-9999999902299>

in[129: ]<9420>
```

I want to create a script that will be able to select the following: `in[ 32: ]<000090>`, `in[ 49: ]<960>`, `out[000: ]<ISO9090-9999999902299>` and `in[129: ]<9420>` and echo them out.

The directory for the logs is `/var/debug/logs`.

Comment: You want to select those lines... based on which kind of selection criteria?

Comment: .sh script when run in unix will select and echo only those fields for they are the required.

Comment: If you want to use grep to select some lines they must have something in common that makes sense, otherwise there's no point in trying to select them... I am asking what do those lines have in common? Why specifically `In[ 32: ]<000090>` for example?

Comment: because they are the problematic fields that a user can understand in that debug.

Comment: like if the messeage is rejected from field -> out[129: ]<ISO0000-99990000"022"00> because of this issue 022
grep -EFn "out[129: ]<ISO0000-9999000002200>" test.debug 
 the printf will be 'out[129: ]<ISO0000-9999000002200>' 
 then i store it in a variable.
 grep another like grep -EFn "in[ 32: ]<000090>" test.debug store it in a variable 
 then echo the variables

Comment: so you only care about that `<XXXX>` code, it doesn't matter the number inside `in[ XX: ]`, am I right?

Comment: Yes true very correct

Comment: If you only care about <XXXX> code and not something inside in [ XX: ] then why you don't want in[ 19: ]<960>  ?

Comment: yes, `fgrep -e 'in[ 32: ]<000090>' -e 'in[ 49: ]<960>' -e '...'` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can just `grep` for every of the error codes you want to match. No need to use `echo` since `grep` already outputs the matching lines.

```
grep -E '000090|960|9420|out\[ *002: *\]<ISO9090-9999999902299>' /var/debug/logs/filename
```

You can use `*` as filename if you want to search in all the files in the folder instead of just one.

Comment: Perfect that works great. is there a where statement in scripting like if fail is from ISO9090-9999999902299 specific position 022 then display those grepped  (000090|960|9420|ISO9090-9999999902299)?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. Do you mean `Out[022: ]<ISO9090-...>`?

Comment: Sorry my English not good. yes sure

Comment: Ok, edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can put all the patterns you want to look for in a file and specify the file on the command line using the -f  flag.

Quoting the man page:

```
-f file, --file=file
            Read one or more newline separated patterns from file.  Empty pattern lines match every input line.
            Newlines are not considered part of a pattern.  If file is empty, nothing is matched.
```

so

```
grep -r -f <your file> /var/debug/logs
```

will give you all lines matching any of the lines from all the files in `/var/debug/logs`

Comment: Trying that one now